# Why do test banners take such a long time to load on device

Tags: admob, ios-simulator, iad

I'm currently working on iAd/AdMob mediation. The test banners in the simulator load almost instantly. At most there is a 3-5 second wait. However, on actual device, sometimes those test banners don't load for 30 seconds or don't even load at all. Nobody waits for ads to load, so i'll never get paid if the ads take so long to load. Does this happen with live ads too or only test ads on device? Is there a code to make the ads load faster on screen?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a bit late, but I hope I can help someone:

The trick is loading the ads some time BEFORE showing them, not at the exact moment when you want to show them. And load them by code, not XML!

Normally I load them when I enter the activity or even in the splash activity (the first loading activity). Then when you want to show them you only need to call ad.show() (in the case of interstitial and video ads).

With banners it's easy too: you create the AdView by code (not xml) and call loadAd, so it loads, but you store the AdView in a variable, instead of placing it in the view. And later on, when you enter the activity with the banner, you add that view to a layout.

EXTRA: Perhaps what you mean: I realized that ads like interstitial and videos sometimes don't load after you already showed them, so in the ad close event, I reset them (I define them again and store it in the same variable), and then they work perfectly.

So, summary:

- Load banners as soon as possible, before showing them.
- Re-create banners once they are closed (interstital and videos) in the close event.

Answer (score 0):

Test banners from production ad unit ids running on test build of the app will take some time to show the ads according to Google AdMob. In my app, the test ads take about 2-3 minutes to show and 3-4 ad requests will be timed out before I get one. Anyhow I did notice that this scenario was happening only from the second launch of the application. [Here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9691433#zippy=%2Cclick-to-view-example-ads-in-test-mode:%7E:text=Ads%20in%20test%20mode%20can%20take%20up%20to%201%20hour%20to%20show%20in%20apps.%20In%20some%20cases%2C%20it%20may%20take%20up%20to%2024%20hours%20for%20test%20ads%20to%20show%20in%20apps.) is the key point in Google AdMob documentation which states that test ads will take some time to load whereas demo ad units will be displaying ads instantly.