# Why are my ads slow to load when I use Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, admob

I have a react-native app and I want to show ads so I added `Admob`.

It worked fine until I added Firebase into the mix, then the ads began to load slower and I don't want that, I just want to test the ads.

I think it's how many users are on the app or how long the user has been active because the ads took 2 hours did not even load. I have tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143854/why-do-test-banners-take-such-a-long-time-to-load-on-device) but it didn't help. I'm very confused why it happening, can anybody help?

Comment: Export your release version then try it on Real Device .. I sure it is will be faster :)

Comment: It is running on a reall device.

Comment: Use also debug better than release ..

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to debug.

Comment: My Bad ! .. Sorry I mean Try release better than debug .. Beacause release is lighter than Debug Version .

Comment: What do you mean release do you mean turn it into apk? I'm so sorry for not understanding I don't know all react-native features.

Comment: Yes .. Then try it into real Device .. You will see more performance ..

Comment: should i remove

            ` debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }`
from android/app/build.gradle ?

Comment: I am not expert but you can keep it .. As you won't puplish to Play Store ..

Comment: It didn't work..

Comment: Which did not work (Exporting Release Version) Or (Or Ads still slow in release version)

Comment: ads still slow in release version

Comment: I noticed that a lot of people asked that in Stack Overflow .. But people are saying the best way is to preload the Ad to show to the User before Leaving the page .. Also I noticed that you already asked the question in Stack Overflow saying you have a lot of dependencies in your App this also may causes the issue ..

Comment: I have tried what i think are the problems in that question yet it didnt work and i posted that question but it didnt get any attention and it wasnt good and clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231036/discussion-between-pirogrammer-and-kevin-m-mansour).